# Unknown addiction

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

If I am addicted to something, but I do not know what I am addicted to, is there such a word to describe that?

Is it appropriate to use "unknown" addiction, since I am not aware of it?

Is there another word for "unknown"?

The addiction has negative connotation therefore I am looking for a negative adjective, if any. All addictions are not bad. Some addictions could be useful.

Comment: Could you provide a sample sentence where you might want to use this?

Comment: Thanks. For example:  "She has this 'word' addiction that is not helping her at all. She should listen to her friends and family."

Comment: In that case you can use **narcotic**. For instance: [*narcotic addiction*](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/narcotic_2)

Comment: If you're addicted you're "hooked".  And you can be [Hooked on Mozart](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001KEVG58?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0).

Comment: You question is ambiguous. I don't know if you are talking about kinds of narcotics or something else like alcohol or drugs or maybe reading books -:) ?

Comment: @PabloZapata I eddited your question. Please feel free to re-insert it with additional clarification if there is something relevant to this question. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[*Idiopathic*: Of unknown cause.](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=3892)

Idiopathic specifically relates to disease, which addiction certainly is considered.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a medical doctor, but I have come across the term [*undiagnosed* condition](http://www.addictionsearch.com/treatment_blog/undiagnosed-and-treated-mental-health-conditions-commonly-result-in-substance-abuse-relapse_187.html). It is used in the following sense:

> An undiagnosed condition is one where someone experiences symptoms but does not have a formal diagnosis. - [Brain and Spine Foundation](http://www.brainandspine.org.uk/undiagnosed-conditions)

**Undiagnosed** conditions can also be [asymptomatic](http://www.beyondceliac.org/celiac-disease/symptoms/). The links relate more broadly to physical and mental health, but the ideas are consistent with what you have described.

Comment: Thank you. I think the term undiagnosed condition is great. I may not use on the same sentence but I will definitely include it in the same paragraph.